# Gatsby.js - proxy to express server

Tags: javascript, json, gatsby

I want to setup proxy for my simple express server. I have added cors policy and everything works perfect when I call api like this:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/tasks')
```

But when i setup proxy in gatsby.config.js like this:

```
proxy: {
    prefix: '/',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000'
  },
```

and call:

```
fetch('/tasks)
```

I'm getting this error:

> Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

How to setup properly proxy in gatsby.js ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can use root as proxy. In gatsby develop, proxy is handled like [this](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/530e0877801253d7935e2e6eed0fe0d7e3126750/packages/gatsby/src/commands/develop.js#L206):

```
app.use(`${prefix}/*`, (req, res) => { ... }
```

So if `prefix` is set to `/`, it'll become `//*` which will not work. Even if it did work like `/*`, all routes from gatsby server will be redirect to proxy server because proxy has higher precedent than the rest of the routes, gatsby wouldn't have any chances to serve any pages at all.

`prefix` has to be a word started with a slash, i.e `/api`:

```
proxy: {
  prefix: '/api',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000'
},
```

Then you can use it:

```
fetch(`/api/tasks`)
```

Comment: have you refreshed `gatsby develop`? any new error message?

Comment: No, still the same error, and API only works good with full path and postman... When I write in browser: localhost:3000/api/tasks it works good, but proxy still doesn't. I'm getting the same error

Comment: Yeah it worked... problem was that API returned empty Array... when Array is not empty your code is working... Many thanks!

Comment: @Freestyle09 ah man, I knew it'd be something from the dev server, glad you got it worked out! When you run into problems again, join https://gatsby.dev/discord — lots of folks can help you out over there

Comment: Yeah, it was weird that this was not working, I got backend code from friend and I didn't checked that because he assured me that all is working properly :) Thanks for invite!

Comment: For me the bug was at `prefix: '/api/custom_path/',`. I had a trailing `/` in the end. Removing it automagically fixed the bug

Answer (score 2):

This should go into a comment, but format is not good so i post as answer. I'm not sure what's the precise cause, but some idea to help you debug.

1. Chance are you received a HTML response with content-type header saying it's a JSON. Verify if this is the case by inspecting the network panel in browser devtools.
2. Make sure that request actually hit your express server. If 1. is true, then it's highly likely it didn't reach express server, the HTML comes from Gatsby's dev server.
3. If both points above are true, then perhaps debug the Gatsby source code to find out why it decide to handle the request instead of forward it. Derek Nguyen pointed out the [location](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/530e0877801253d7935e2e6eed0fe0d7e3126750/packages/gatsby/src/commands/develop.js#L206). It's also a express server so should be fine to you.

Comment: @Freestyle09 yeah, I know. Question is, how exactly not work?

Comment: @Freestyle09 Try answer these questions (methods already given above):  1. When it "doesn't work", what exactly does the response looks like?   2. Are you 100% sure that request hit your express server?

Comment: solid answer actually. I've used this feature & tested it again back when I gave my answer & it always worked.  @Freestyle09 could you update your answer with the new proxy setting? For completeness, we need to know if the proxy is actually hitting your local backend, you can do this by logging request to your local server.

Comment: It only works with full url adress: localhost:3000/tasks ... When I am trying to set proxy I'm getting the error above. Same error on /api/tasks or on only /tasks ... Unhandled rejection...

Comment: @Freestyle09 Yeah, glad to know that. Stop repeating yourself, do sth. Figure it out.